Spark: cast to DateType value with only month and year
Given date-value with month and year:
03.2020

I tried to cast it to DateType as following:
to_timestamp(col("Date"), "MM.yyyy").cast(DateType)

But this return something, that I did't expect:
 2017-03-01

Returned value contains additional "01" (day value), and reorder month and year. So the expected value is "03.2020"
Following this Advice ,
I also tried:
 date_format(col("Date"), "MM.yyyy")

But in this case the function returns null.
What am I doing wrong ?

This should work:
dataframe
.withColumn("as_date",date_format((to_date('string_date', 'MM.yyyy')).cast('timestamp'),"MM.yyyy"))
.show()

Essentially you need to pass timestamp to date_format instead of string column
Input:
+-----------+
|string_date|
+-----------+
|    03.2020|
+-----------+

Output:
+-----------+-------+
|string_date|as_date|
+-----------+-------+
|    03.2020|03.2020|
+-----------+-------+

